# Hiding a frame in java upon a button click

Tags: java, swing, button, hide, frame

I am trying to hide a frame once a button is clicked. The "Register" button should open up a frame where a user can register, and that works, but I am trying to hide the previous frame and I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's my code:

MainPage.java

```
package Practice_1;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Ivan 
 */
public class MainPage extends JPanel 
{
    JButton regButton, logButton, listButton;
    JLabel homeMessage;
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    public MainPage()
    {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

        homeMessage = new JLabel("Please select an option below:");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(homeMessage, gbc);

        regButton = new JButton("Register");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        regButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                //System.out.println("clicked");
                RegisterPage regFrame = new RegisterPage();

                JFrame register = new JFrame();
                register.setTitle("Registration");
                register.setSize(300,200);
                register.setVisible(true);
                register.add(regFrame);
                new MainPage().setVisible(false);  / THIS DOES NOT WORK

            }
        });
        add(regButton, gbc);

        logButton = new JButton("Log in");
        gbc.ipadx = 40;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(logButton, gbc);

        listButton = new JButton("Customer list");
        gbc.ipadx = 40;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        add(listButton, gbc);

        JFrame home = new JFrame();

        home.setTitle("Main menu");
        home.setSize(300,200);
        home.setResizable(false);
        home.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        home.setVisible(true);
        home.add (mainFrame);


    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MainPage mainFrame = new MainPage();





    }
}
```

RegisterPage.java

```
package Practice_1;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Ivan
 */
public class RegisterPage extends JPanel {


    //JButton regButton, logButton, listButton;
    JLabel homeMessage;
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    public RegisterPage()
    {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

        homeMessage = new JLabel("Register new user:");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(homeMessage, gbc);


    }

}
```

Comment: This comes up time and time again. Don't use another JFrame. Have the dialog window be a JDialog.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for more info. on the matter referenced by @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acording to your code you are trying to hide `JPanel` instead of `JFrame`. My suggestion is to  use

```
public class MainPage extends JFrame
```

than instantiate your `JPanel` like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

and to add components on that panel. To hide your MainPage you can call:

```
this.setVisible(false);
```

but it would be better if you use:

```
this.dispose();
```

Comment: I am not able to use 'this' inside `
  closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.exit(0);
    
   }
  });`

Comment: @user3153014 Use it like: `MainPane.this`