# Adding multiple frames

Tags: java, swing, frames

If I want that on clicking a certain button the current frame should close and a new frame with new content should appear, how can I do that?
For example, I have a login button, which on clicking leads to a new frame and closing the old frame.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
 setVisible(false);//for closing the old frame
```

Now how can I add a new frame?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

You should use as you did, this.setvisible(false) or this.dispose(); depending on your requirements.

Theres a few posts that cover it but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278137/hiding-a-frame-in-java-upon-a-button-click) for specifics.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();

//added new frame, set it to visible
frame.setVisible(true);
 //hide old one with setVisible or dispose()
this.setVisible(false); //or you'd be better using  this.dispose();
}
```